# jQuery Fileupload iframe transport ie8 sending wrong request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-file-upload

I have a fileuploader modeled after Ryan Bates railscast that works perfectly in any browser that supports XHR requests but I'm having trouble figuring out why IE8 is not making the correct request to the server.

My form looks something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/paul-zaich/avatars" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new-uploaded-avatar" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="8K3821XQAVK8//GR2tqNFPuil+KMn1nP8MMXefPSczY="></div>

<div class="text-center photo-uploader">
<div class="hide">
  <input accept="image/*" class="hidden-file-field" id="avatar_photo" name="avatar[photo]" type="file">
</div>
     <a href="#" class=" btn btn-primary manual-filechooser">
       <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Select a photo
     </a>    <span class="avatar-help-text">or drag and drop your photo here. (.jpg, .png, .gif    formats)</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Normally when a file is uploaded, I get a request like this

```
Started POST "/users/paul-zaich/avatars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-02 16:29:57 -0700
Chrome 29.0.1547.76 (Macintosh, OS X 10.8.4), JS enabled
Processing by AvatarsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8K3821XQAVK8//GR2tqNFPuil+KMn1nP8MMXefPSczY=", "avatar"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbfc1a1bd68 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-10-02 at 6.07.02 AM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar[photo]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-10-02 at 6.07.02 AM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/_8/xgsyh3453f52nj6gtn64yh580000gn/T/RackMultipart20131002-6891-xix1c2>>}, "user_id"=>"paul-zaich"}
```

With IE8 however, it seems to be completely ignoring the action url in the form and the method type as well. Here's what my server log looks like

```
Started GET "/settings/[object%20Object]" for 172.16.130.1 at 2013-10-02 16:20:56 -0700
Internet Explorer 8.0 (Windows, Windows 7)
Processing by UsersController#edit as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"[object object]"}
```

My fileupload call looks something like this (simplified)

```
$('#new-uploaded-avatar').fileupload({
  dataType: 'script',
  dropZone: $('.user-avatar-uploader-container'),
  add: function (e, data) {
    data.context = $(tmpl("avatar-upload", data.files[0]));
    $('.photo-uploader').hide();
    $('.upload-catch').append(data.context);
    data.submit();
  }
});
```

Any ideas?